# How would you unsuspend a computer using a bash script?

Tags: bash, power-management, scripts

How I can unsuspend my computer with a bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm-suspend
sleep 10m
{unsuspend command}
```

Comment: The script would need to interface to a USB-controlled robotic arm that presses the power button on your laptop.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is wake on lan

Answer (score 4):

After your computer have been suspended, nothing more will get executed, so your bash-script will not continue running until it you have woken it up.

You need to put your script on another machine (on the same local network), as Cubiq said, and use wake on lan (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) to wake-up your machine.

Here is a ubuntu-guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan